# Mathematical odds of picking letters

Tags: probability

What are the odds of picking two pre-selected non-sequential letters in order out of a $26$ letter alphabet, i.e. $D$ then $S$, not $S$ then $D$? One chance only.

Comment: $26^{-2}$, it's exactly one out of $26^2$ many possible outcomes.

Comment: @user155124 Nope, he said non-sequential, so after d is picked, c and e could not be picked

Comment: @user155124 or maybe he means that the second letter must come after the first, any amount later, but not before. Im not 100% sure

Comment: Are we sampling with replacement or without replacement? And are the two letters specified in advance?

Comment: Hello, yes, the letters are specified in advance, but their position in the alphabet is not important. I think non-sequential was misleading. They can be ANY two letters. They happen to be D and S, and it happens that D is picked before S.

Comment: First are the selection of the two letters the same event? Or separate, and are you done selecting letters, or will you continue to select letters. If you continue to select letters that needs to be specified or the answer would assume you selected wrong (1/26)(1/26), or 1/26^2 but that wouldn't be correct for your scenario is suggesting either two separate events (like above) however selecting from a different amount of letters than 26. What exactly do you mean sequential? Picking D before the next event of selecting letters? That's wouldn't be 1/26 as mentioned by others because selecting an

Answer (score 1):

if I understand the question correctly, what's the probability that you select a two letters from the English alphabet, such that the second one comes after the first. Use the law of total probability:
$$
P(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{26}P(X|Y=k)P(Y=k) = \frac{25}{26} \cdot P(X=A) + \frac{24}{26} \cdot P(X=B) +\ldots
$$

of course $P(X=j) = \frac{1}{26}$. Can you handle from here?

EDIT: you may want ot use the identity $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: Hello Alex, I'm not a mathematician, and need some more help. Specifically the letters are D and S, and they are pre-specified, i.e. first D, then S. These are the only two letters picked out of the English alphabet in that order in a single try. What are the 'odds'? 1 in 600?, 1 in 6000? etc.

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, there are two options: 1)with replacement, then this probability is $\frac{1}{26^2}$ because after sampling 'D' 'you put it back' and the trials are independent, 2) without replacement, this probability is $\frac{1}{26} \cdot \frac{1}{25}$, because you don't 'put' 'D' back. This is if the order is important (i.e. DS, not SD).